# Sphinx how to use wordforms with soundex?

Tags: sphinx, soundex

I am using sphinx with soundex morphology. I want to use wordworms.

Which form of word do I need to use like a result?

```
call keywords ('azori', 'test', 1);

+------+-----------+------------+------+------+
| qpos | tokenized | normalized | docs | hits |
+------+-----------+------------+------+------+
| 1    | azori     | a260       | 1550 | 1551 |
+------+-----------+------------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In wordforms I need to use

```
azouri > azori
```

or

```
azouri > a260
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is is probably the critical bit from the documentation:

> `wordforms` .. It can also be used to implement stemming exceptions, because stemming is not applied to words found in the forms list.

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-wordforms

... ie stemming (actually morphology, and hence soundex) algorithm is not run on words/tokens transformed by wordforms. Hence yes you do have to manually 'soundex' the destination keyword.